# Mapping 2D StreamPlot on 2D non-planar curve in 3D space

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Just wondering how I would map the following `StreamPlot`:

```
ClearAll;
Eq1 = x'[t] == s*(y[t] - x[t]);
Eq2 = y'[t] == r*x[t] - y[t] - x[t]*(x[t]*y[t]/b);
Manipulate[
StreamPlot[{s*(y - x), 
r*x - y - x*(x*y/b)}, {x, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, 
Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1}, {y, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, 
Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],
Delimiter,
{{T, 50}, 0.1, 100},
{{r, 1}, 1, 35},
{{s, 10}, 0, 100},
{{b, 8/3}, 0, 100},
SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

on the 2D surface in 3D Space:

```
Plot3D[x*y*(3/8) == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Thank you in advance for your help in resolving this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest variant is to use the `StreamPlot` as texture and put it on the surface. With `strPlot` being your stream plot:

```
img = Show[strPlot, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   ImagePadding -> None];
Plot3D[x*y*(3/8) == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 512]],
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but this does not preserve the coordinate geometry on the surface. A coordinate in 3D space does not correspond to the same point on the 2D surface of the mapped image.

Comment: @Jelmes Please look at the related options. What you need to do is to fix the mapping. For this, you can use `TextureCoordinateFunction` and also look at `TextureCoordinateScaling`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to take the graphics primitives in the stream plot and replace the 2D coordinates by their corresponding 3D coordinates. It would look like this:

```
Eq1 = x'[t] == s*(y[t] - x[t]);
Eq2 = y'[t] == r*x[t] - y[t] - x[t]*(x[t]*y[t]/b);

T = 50;
r = 1;
s = 10;
b = 8./3.;

streamPlot = StreamPlot[
   {s*(y - x), r*x - y - x*(x*y/b)},
   {x, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1},
   {y, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1},
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
   ];

primitives = ReplaceRepeated[
   Flatten@streamPlot[[1, 2, All, 3 ;;]],
   Arrow[{a___, {x_Real, y_Real}, b___}] :> Arrow[{a, {x, y, 3./8. x y}, b}]
   ];

Show[
  Plot3D[
  3./8. x y, 
  {x, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1},
  {y, -Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] - 1, Sqrt[b*(r - 1)] + 1},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> White
  ],
  Graphics3D[primitives]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note especially this line:

```
Arrow[{a___, {x_Real, y_Real}, b___}] :> Arrow[{a, {x, y, 3./8. x y}, b}]
```

It's not clear how you want to map the 2D coordinates to the 3D space, if you need to change it then this is the line that you will want to adapt.

The line

```
Flatten@streamPlot[[1, 2, All, 3 ;;]]
```

was found out by experimenting. Essentially, I looked at `streamPlot // FullForm` and started selecting parts to see what would happen, until I had isolated the graphics primitives.

Once you have mapped the 2D coordinates into 3D correctly then you may find that you want to change the styling, that the arrowheads are too large or something like that. This can be done with a replacement rule similarly to what was done for the coordinates. You will simply replace the `ArrowHeads` directives in `primitives` with your own version.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. This does indeed preserves 3D coordinate geometry on the surface.